# Getting Facebook Interests graph api call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the users liked Facebook pages, here is my code:

```
exports.checkUserInterests = function (fbaccountID,fbModule) {

    var facebookModule = fbModule;
;

    //code to get the list of facebook likes for any given user
    facebookModule.requestWithGraphPath('me/interests', {}, 'GET', function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        alert(e.result);
    } else if (e.error) {
        alert(e.error);
    } else {
        alert('Unknown response');
    }
});


};
```

My Permissions is set as following:

```
//set permissions for graph api
var permissions = ['user_friends', 'user_interests', 'user_birthday', 'user_photos', 'basic_info'];
```

I an returning an empty json array, is my request correct?

Thanks

Comment: Are you testing as you or someone that have a role on the app? If the user doesn't have a role on the app you need to get your app approved

Comment: as me,i am using my own account. I am able to make other api calls fine with it.

Comment: Then I suggest to debug the access token to make sure that you have those permissions

Comment: other then that, is my api call correct?

Answer (score 0):

I use a different call to get the Facebook Likes of a user, maybe thats the problem.

For example, if I want to know if the user likes a page with id: xxxxx, I do a GET call to "me/likes/xxxxxx" and see if the result is true.

For this to work, you should have the permissions to user_likes.

Comment: whats the difference between interests and likes? Are likes for the pages the user has liked?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have a game, and it's fan page. And in game, I want to show a popup to the user if he hasn't already liked the fan page of the game. I accomplish that with the code above